# Is there any gem that can help Activerecord Association attributes mapping?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The gem can help like this :

```
class Book
  belongs_to :author
end

book = Book.first
book.author_name  #=> same as book.author.name
book.provide( :author_name, :title ) #=> will automatically map like this: { :title => book.title, :author_name => book.author.name }
```

Is there any gem help ?? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the rails [Delegate](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) module:

```
class Invoice < Struct.new(:client)
  delegate :name, :address, :to => :client, :prefix => :customer
end

invoice = Invoice.new(john_doe)
invoice.customer_name    # => "John Doe"
invoice.customer_address # => "Vimmersvej 13"
```